# JavaFX 11 - Gimp Toolkit library not found - (glassgtk2)

Tags: javafx, gtk, java-11

When running my JavaFX 11 test app on Linux, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glassgtk2 in java.library.path:
```

I can see the folder here that appears to contain the library I need?

```
/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0
```

and I have tried adding this when I run the app:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0
```

but I get the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glassgtk2 in java.library.path: [/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0]
```

**Full trace here:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glassgtk2 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:268)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glassgtk2 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:150)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:52)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:182)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:171)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
```

Comment: Does adding `-Djdk.gtk.version=2` help here?  https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/jfx-11/doc-files/release-notes-11.md#switch-default-gtk-version-to-3 ... Might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333364/drag-and-drop-working-differently-in-java-11-vs-java-8

Comment: No - just tried this

Comment: This looks related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467499/javafx-os-x-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-sw/53467564#53467564). Are you using the SDK jars or you have the jars from a different library folder?

Comment: Yes I'm using the sdk libs, javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib

Comment: The exception you have posted says otherwise: `/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib`, not `.../javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib` in there. Can you post how you run your app? Do you add `--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib`?

Comment: I think this question needs to include command line as Jose asks as otherwise we can't see if you've followed the instructions to use --add-modules.

Comment: Latest error 

    Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/devel/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/libprism_sw.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/devel/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/libprism_sw.so)

I am now moving to a different version of Redhat Linux that has a later version of libc.

Comment: Command to run was:
java   -Djdk.gtk.verbose=true -Djava.library.path=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:/home/devel/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib:/lib64  --module-path /home/devel/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib -Dprism.verbose=true --add-modules=javafx.controls MenuTest11 &